# Replace string in the first file it is found

Tags: bash, sed, natural-sort

I have a bunch of files named like this:

```
chapter1.tex
chapter2.tex
chapter3.tex
...
chapter 10.tex
chapter 11.tex
etc.
```

I am trying to use `sed` to find and replace the first instance of `AAAAAA` with `ZZZZZZ` within all of the files.

```
sed -i "0,/AAAAAA/s//ZZZZZZ/" chapter*.tex
```

I tried this above command, but there are two problems:

1. It finds and replaces the first instance of `AAAAAA` within each file. I want only the first instance among all files.
2. I suspect, like many Bash tools, it doesn't properly sort my files in order. E.g. if I type `ls` then `chapter10.tex` is listed before `chapter1.tex`. It is critical it searches the files in order of the chapters.

How to use Bash tools to find and replace first instance, from among a large list of files, so only the first instance in the first found file is replaced, while also respecting the file order (`chapter1.tex` is first, `chapter10.tex` is tenth)?

Comment: I don't think this is a task can be done by `sed` alone, but am happy to accept the contrary, glad that you asked.

Comment: I will rewrite the question, I think other tools typical on systems running Bash prompt will be fine, didn't mean for the wording to sound like only `sed` is okay. If `awk` or other tools found on a Linux computer's base install can do it, fine.

Comment: If you use names like `chapter01.tex` instead they'll be sorted correctly in filename expansions, btw.

Comment: The problem is other code is looking for chapter1.tex, code that simply increments "1" to "2", etc. and converting all that code to look for "01" was much more complicated.

Comment: One call to `sed` can totally handle it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a bash loop based solution that will work with filenames such as `chapter 10.tex` i.e. filenames with spaces etc:

```sh
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
   if grep -q 'AAAAAA' "$file"; then
      echo "changing $file"
      sed -i '0,/AAAAAA/s//ZZZZZZ/' "$file"
      break
   fi
done < <(printf '%s\0' chapter*.tex | sort -z -V)
```

This is assuming both `sed` and `sort` are from gnu utils.

---

If you have gnu awk 4+ version that supports in-place editing i.e. `-i inplace` then you can replace `grep + sed` with single `awk`:

```sh
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
   awk -i inplace '!n {n=sub(/AAAAAA/, "ZZZZZZ")} 1;
   END {exit !n}' "$file" && break
done < <(printf '%s\0' chapter*.tex | sort -z -V)
```

Answer (score 4):

With the complete GNU toolchest you don't need a loop.

```
printf '%s\0' chapter*.tex    \
| sort -zV                    \
| xargs -0 grep -FlZ 'AAAAAA' \
| head -zn1                   \
| xargs -0r sed -i 's/AAAAAA/ZZZZZZ/'
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed and grep):

```
grep -ns 'AAAAAA' chapter{1..9999}.txt | head -1 |
sed -nE 's#([^:]*):([^:]*):.*#sed -i "\2s/AAAAAA/ZZZZZZ/" \1#e'
```

Use grep and bash's braces expansion to identify the one possible matching file and line number and build a sed script to update that file at that line number.

N.B. Brace expansion generates the filenames in the correct order and the `-s` command line option for grep suppresses the non-existent files messages.

---

Alternative using GNU parallel:

```
grep -sno 'AAAAAA' chapter{1..9999}.txt | head -1 |
parallel --colsep : sed '{2}s/{3}/ZZZZZZ/' {1}
```

Comment: I'd also add some `^` ans `$` anchors in that first pattern match. That should handle any colons in the data, since the filenames are a known format that doesn't have colons, and the count at the end won't either. That's generally a slick application of `/e`.

Comment: @Sundeep Ah yes! The `1` restricts it to the head (first file) but my test data didn't take into account the possibility of `:` occurring in the input data. See edit.

Comment: Yeah, I did spot that `1`, but what I meant is `grep` will continue to search all the files. Which I think can be avoided to some extent with `head` or even adding `q` to `sed` instead of `1` line addressing.

Answer (score 1):

### #update

I stand on the backs of giants, lol

Kudos to @potong for a great sorting solution with brace expension! That means this whole thing can be reduced to a single-process one-liner:

```
sed -i '0,/^AAA/{ /^AAA/{ s/AAA/ZZZ/; h; } }; ${ x; /./{x;q;}; x; }' chapter\ {[0-9],[0-9][0-9]}.tex
```

### #edit

As pointed out, the original solution below would process and change the first occurrence in every file, and does not correct the file order.  @anubhava already provided an excellent, elegant sorting solution on which I will not try to improve.

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do lst+=( "$file" ); done < <(printf '%s\0' chapter*.tex | sort -z -V)
```

This creates a list of the filenames in proper order which can be passed to a single call of `sed` to process them *en masse*.

To apply that to ordering to a `sed`-based solution and only hit the first occurrence in *any* file -

```
sed -i '0,/^AAA/{ /^AAA/{ s/AAA/ZZZ/; h; } }; ${ x; /./{x;q;}; x; }' "${lst[@]}"
```

This will look through each file and change the first occurrence it finds in that file, `h`olding the line where it first finds it. On the last line of each file it e`x`changes the current line for the hold buffer and checks to see if after the swap there is anything in the pattern buffer. If there is not, it swaps it back and continues. If there *is*, it swaps it back and `q`uits, skipping all subsequent files.

While somewhat complicated, this does not spawn processes for each file.

---

#### Original

---

Use a double condition -

```
sed -i '0,/AAAAAA/{ /AAAAAA/s/AAAAAA/ZZZZZZ/ }' chapter*.tex
```

To see the same general logic in action:

```
$: cat a.tex b.tex
111
AAA
BBB
AAA
222

111
AAA
BBB
AAA
222

$: sed -i '0,/^AAA/{ /^AAA/s/AAA/ZZZ/; }' *.tex
$: cat a.tex b.tex
111
ZZZ
BBB
AAA
222

111
ZZZ
BBB
AAA
222
```

`'0,/^AAA/` is right, as it ranges from the start of the file to the *first* occurrance of the target string.

`{` opens a block, in which we can use a second search to make sure it only affects the targeted string.

Inside the block, `/^AAA/s/AAA/ZZZ/;` substitutes the AAA string and ignores all the records before it. `}` closes the block. All records after will be untouched.

Comment: this doesn't address two issues: 1) after a match is found, no more files should be affected 2) sort order of `*.tex`

Comment: This will not respect file order, though - I'll add something for that.

Comment: I missed that. Thanks for the callout. Will fix or remove.

Comment: Kudos to @potong for a great sorting solution with brace expension! That means this whole thing can be reduced to a single-process one-liner: `sed -i '0,/^AAA/{ /^AAA/{ s/AAA/ZZZ/; h; } }; ${ x; /./{x;q;}; x; }' chapter\ {[0-9],[0-9][0-9]}.tex` :)